# How to join query on three tables with multiple colums im my sql?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables like this:

**mandihindi**

```
mandihini | mandieng
--------------
  agra      | आगरा
  fatehabad | फ़तेहाबाद  
  jagner    | जागनेर
```

**commodityhindi**

```
commodeng| commohin
------------------
 Jai    |जय  
 Jo     | जो
 paddy  | धान
```

**commoditywise**

```
mandi      | commodity| price  |
----------------------------------
 agra      | paddy      | 123.00 
 fatehabad | paddy      | 224.00 
 jagner    | paddy      | 1286.098
 agra      | jo         | 123.00 
 fatehabad | jo         | 224.00 
 jagner    | jo         | 1286.098
 agra      | jai        | 123.00 
 fatehabad | jai        | 224.00 
 jagner    | jai        | 1286.098
```

**I want to get result something like this*

```
     mandihindi  |  price 
    --------------------------
          आगरा   |    123.00 
        फ़तेहाबाद   |    224.00 
         जागनेर   |    1286.098
```

Description :
  there is no primary key in any table
I want all records where
**commoditywise*  = 'paddy'

I tried  but  i  am not able to fetch the data correctly. 
Please help.

Thanks in advance
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as

```
select
ch.mandieng,
cw.price
from commoditywise cw
inner join mandihindi ch on ch.mandihini = cw.mandi
where 
cw.commodity = 'paddy'
```

Comment: This should return exactly what you have in the question check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b78a3f/1, or you want something else to be returned ?

Answer (score 0):

No need to join table "commodityhindi", your expected output will be get by below query

```
    select 
mh.mandieng
,cw.price
from mandihindi mh
  inner join commoditywise cw
    on mh.mandihini = cw.mandi
where cw.commodity =  'paddy'
```

Comment: dear this query is not providing desired output